# EC2 Micro with NGINX

Tags: php, nginx, amazon-ec2, ubuntu-12.04

I have an EC2 Micro running Ubuntu 12.04. I have assigned it an EIP (23.21.213.236) and I am pointing my domain name A records to this IP.

The domain I am trying to access with is utoolsandfixings.co.uk, this should show a page saying "Server Found".

I have tried restarting NGINX after I made all my amendments.

I have installed NGINX on the server and setup a VHost, set up a symlink etc. The VHOST is as follows:

```
server {
    listen 80; ## listen for ipv4
    server_name utoolsandfixings.co.uk; ## change this to your own domain name
    # I find it really useful for each domain & subdomain to have its own error and access log
    error_log /var/log/nginx/utoolsandfixings.co.uk.error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/utoolsandfixings.co.uk.access.log;
    location / {
            # Change this to the folder where you want to store your website
            root /var/www/utoolsandfixings.co.uk/;
            index index.html index.htm index.php;
    }
    # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
    #
    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
            root /var/www/nginx-default;
    }
    # We haven't setup FastCGI yet, but lets configure this now anyways
    #
    # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
    location ~ \.php$ {
            fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            # again, change the directory here to your website's root directory make sure to leave $fastcgi_script_name; on the end!
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /home/meltingice_net/public_html$fastcgi_script_name;
            include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
    }
```

}

Also my nginx.conf

```
user www-data;
worker_processes 4;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
pid /var/run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
    # multi_accept on;
}
http {
    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    sendfile on;
    #tcp_nopush on; keepalive_timeout 0;
    keepalive_timeout 2;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    gzip on;
    gzip_disable msie6;
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

Any help at all would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is NGINX running (started) on the instance? `/etc/init.d/nginx status`

Suspect that this is a firewalling issue, have you assigned a security group to the instance that allows HTTP? There is a reasonable guide [here](http://cloud-computing.learningtree.com/2010/09/24/understanding-amazon-ec2-security-groups-and-firewalls/).

Additionally, have you checked there isn't a local firewall on the instance dropping incoming traffic? `sudo iptables --list`

Comment: EDIT: this has been sorted. Excellent! That seems to have fixed my no response problem (HTTP security groups). I'm now getting a No input file specified error. Is that something wrong with my configuration?

Comment: @GaryDevenay suggest you make a new question about the other problem, it'll give you a better chance of getting an answer, more quickly too.